# Meaning of a quote in movie Casino Royale (2006)

Tags: meaning, figures-of-speech, rhetoric, cinema

> **Vesper Lynd:** There are dinner jackets and dinner jackets; this is
>   the latter. And I need you looking
>   like a man who belongs at that table.

Here what does the line "There are dinner jackets and dinner jackets" means?

Comment: This is an example of witty dialogue. We expect that from a James Bond character. It makes those of us who *do* understand it feel a little superior ... Am I wrong, or am I wrong?

Comment: Another movie example for you Udayan ... in **The Thomas Crown Affair**, Pierce Brosnan says to Rene Russo ... "Do you wanna dance, or do you wanna dance?"

Comment: Darn - I always thought her name in the book was Vespers, plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like saying, "There are men, and there are men."

It really depends on the context. But in this context, I reckon Vesper Lynd is really saying:

> There are alright dinner jackets, and there are good dinner jackets; this is the latter...

"This is the latter" refers to the second of the dinner jackets, which I am presuming, is "good". (I haven't watched the movie)

It's just another way of saying about the difference between two things of the same type, but different quality.

Edit:

Quoting @Unreason:

> To determine which one is better you have to provide more context. Specifically, if the sentence 'And I need you ... at that table.' is affirming the choice of the dinner jacket, then the second one is a better choice. If it is opposing then the second one is a worse choice.

Comment: Thanks @Ham for the answer, but here my doubt is why always later is good? Why not earlier (first) can be good. Is this a commonly used phrase in English? If someone says " There are dinner jackets and dinner jackets; this is the EARLIER(/prior). And I need you looking like a man who belongs at that table." Would this be correct?

Comment: You would probably say "this is the former", but I suppose, yes, that would also be acceptable

Comment: @Udayan: The latter in the expression is not always better, but it's always "more". You could say "There are bad days, and there are *bad days*", where the latter would be really really bad days.

Comment: To determine which one is better you have to provide more context. Specifically, if the sentence 'And I need you ... at that table.' is affirming the choice of the dinner jacket, then the second one is a better choice. If it is opposing then the second one is a worse choice.

Comment: @Unreason, would you mind if I put that in, or should I leave it?

Comment: @Exactly @Unreason, So if someone says, _There are shirts and there are shirts. This one is the later. I want you looking like a begger.._ Then here former is good shirt and later is ugly. (Sorry for bad example! :)

Comment: @Udayan, LOL , good example!

Comment: @Ham and Bacon, feel free to do whatever you like with the comments I make :)

Comment: @Udayan the term is 'latter' not 'later'. It means the second of two mentioned 'things' - in this case a dinner jacket. 'Former' refers to the first dinner jacket. As far as 'there are dinner jackets, and then there are dinner jackets' - it's comparing the quality of the item. One could also say, 'There are cars, and then there are cars.'  One could be a Yugo, the other a Ferrari - normally speaking the Ferrari is of much higher quality and LOOKS nicer. They're both cars, to be sure - but which one would you rather be seen in?

Comment: @Darwy.. yes. That was a typo..

Comment: It is incorrect to say you "need more context" to determine which is better.  The latter is always "more" of whatever quality is being discussed.  Exactly as Guffa explained.

Comment: @Joe Blow, I agree that the latter is always "more". However that does not mean that context is insignificant. More of good thing is better. More of bad thing is worse.

Comment: @unre Yes, as I said things are exactly, precisely, to the letter, absolutely ... as guffa explained!   I am in 100000% agreement with @guffa.

Answer (score 14):

It means that there are ordinary, run-of-the mill dinner jackets, and then there are *special*, well-cut, expensive dinner jackets, of the sort that a millionaire, master criminal or international secret agent would wear.

The idiom can be used for other things too:

> I've tried pizza and I don't really like it.
>
> Ah, but there's pizza, and there's *pizza*. Don't write it off until you've tried pizza from Mario's...

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what she meant. In this movie, James Bond wasn't yet as sophisticated as he would later become, when he would no longer need that kind of advice.

Comment: There is a distinction between idiom and a figure: idioms refer to exact phrases, figures to patterns. This one is a figure. :)

Comment: @unreason -- that's interesting.  I do believe you, but do you have some reference for that?  I've often wondered about exactly how to refer to such "patterns" (I sometimes say "forms").  Do you have a reference that ses one would not use "idiom" for such a pattern?

Comment: @Joe Blow, yes, there are references, but it is a bit too long for a comment; take wikipedia's definition of idiom. Notice two things, first they say there are around 25 thousand idiomatic expressions. The number is not important, but it would be really strange if that referred to patterns and not to instances. The other clue is: 'common use of that expression that is separate from the *literal* meaning or definition of the words of which it is made.' Something can not be literal if it is a pattern. There are other arguments, but as I said, it is a bit too lengthy for comments.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for the reply.  I'm afraid I largely dismiss wikipedia (in particular, wikipedia means nothing in deciding on the definition of words), but I will check out the article for sure, so thanks.  I'm afraid I don't understand your other comments: You say "it would be really strange if [25,000] referred to patterns and not to instances". But, it would be completely normal to refer to N (say, 25,000) patterns. (I do it every day in mathematical or programming work.)

Comment: You also say "Something can not be literal if it is a pattern."   Again that one makes no sense to me -- sets where each member is literal are commonplace.  Imagine a form "X is really really really tasty!" Where X could be any food.  Each instance of the form is perfectly literal.  I can't see literalness having any connection to patterns one way or the other?  (Patterns, and/or instantiations of same, can be either literal or not.)

Comment: Actually just for the record, I can't see any relationship, at all, between literality and idiom.   Some idiom is utterly literal, and some idiom is dadaist.  Now, I read the wikipedia article. It's useless, so that's out.  For now, I can't really see any reason that one wouldn't refer to a figure/pattern as "idiomatic".  Hence, "there's X and then there's X" is indeed idiomatic speech in English.  (It would seem?) BTW if you find comments too short, just keep going in the next one  :)  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

There are answers and then there are *answers*.

This is, in wider sense, a [ploce](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/ploce.htm) : *The repetition of a single word for rhetorical emphasis*. The term is from Gk. *plekein*, "to plait". Also sp. *ploche*, *ploke*, *conduplicatio*, *diaphora*, *doubler*.

In this case, specifically, it could be:

1) [Antanaclasis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/antanaclasis.htm) (from Gk. *anti* “against or back,” *ana* “up” and *klasis* “a breaking”. Also sp. *anaclasis*, *refractio*, “the rebounde”, “word-clashing”)

> The repetition of a word or phrase whose meaning changes in the second instance.
>
> - In the following example, **antanaclasis** occurs with an entire phrase whose meaning alters upon repetition:
>     *"If you aren't **fired with enthusiasm**, you will be **fired with enthusiasm**." —Vince Lombardi*

2) [Diaphora](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/D/diaphora.htm) (Gk. “distinction, variance”)

> Repetition of a common name so as to perform two logical functions: to designate an individual and to signify the qualities connoted by that individual's name or title.
>
> - Example:
>     *"**Boys** will be **boys**."*

Out of these two possibilities, *antanaclasis* is definitively a better choice as the second figure, *diaphora*, refers to *ploce* of  common names.

The *antanaclasis* fits because in the expression

> There are **dinner jackets** and **dinner jackets**.

the phrase takes different meaning, in one case it means an ordinary dinner jacket and in another a dinner jacket that would fit at "that table".

Comment: Thanks @Unreason! That is the perfect technical answer for the question. I have already accepted an answer, I won't change it.. but upvoting your answer.

Comment: Dear downvoter, I would love to improve my answer, but I can't see what is wrong with it. Could you elaborate on the down-vote?

Comment: This answer is 100% incorrect.  In antanaclasis, the **meaning changes** between the two uses.  That is completely irrelevant to the well-known form "There is X, and then there is X."  Specifically in "There is X and then there is X" the two "X" are indeed **exactly the same thing**.  Very simply ,the phrase means "Different quality levels of X exists: ordinary ones and extraordinary ones."

Comment: @Joe Blow, I have considered your arguments before posting the answer and found them not applying. Well, except your opinion on ploce, which I am afraid is just plain wrong (see examples at http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/ploceterm.htm, and also definition at rhetoric.byu.edu); *ploce is used to describe **any** rhetorical repetition of a word*. So, on that account, I believe that you are in obvious contradiction with the references (and you don't provide references for the idea that ploce would only apply to Churchill's example)...

Comment: on the account of two other arguments, as I said, I have considered them before posting. I will put in my arguments in the edit of the answer itself.

Comment: @Unreason - Hi unreason. You have answered at length about ploche (ploce, if you prefer).  If I go to your second reference, it says in clear type "The repetition of a single word for rhetorical emphasis."  [That's the 'Churchill style' notion.] Emphasis is not involved in the question at hand here.  When I go to your first reference at the fine etymology site "about.com", Mr Nordquist says it is "repetition of a word .. with a new or more specific sense."  (Each one of his examples are of the "Vogue / Vogue" form where the meaning wittily changes: first a physical magazine, then a fashion.)

Comment: Regarding antanaclasis, as you know it is "repetition [where] meaning changes in the second instance."  (Such as the witty Vogue/Vogue example.) In the idiom at hand, it means exactly the same thing both times. It means "dinner jacket" (!) both times. You are arguing that the second time it means a dinner jacket, BUT, a really good one. So for you, "a really good car" is a *different thing* from "a car."  I would just say that this well known idiomatic form seems a long way from any well-known antanaclasis.  (Indeed, you brought up many lists of antanaclasis: none contain the idiom at hand.)

Comment: @JoeBlow let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/756/discussion-between-unreason-and-joe-blow)